# Show that if no point in $S$ is a limit point of $S^c$, then $S$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to show that

> if no point in $S$ is a limit point of $S^c$, then $S$ is open

This seems like crazy simple, but I am stuck

Proof by contradiction:

> By contradiction suppose a point $p \in S$ is a limit point of the
>   complement $S^c$, then hence there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ in $S^c$
>   such that $p_n \to p \in S$...

But this means $S^c$ could be open, since by definition $p$ does not have to be in $S^c$, then I have shown that $S$ is closed. There is no contradiction in this argument.

What to do!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $x$ is a limit point of $S^c$ if every open ball around $x$ intersect $S^c$.

A point $x$ is not a limit point of $S^c$ if there exists an open ball around $x$ that does not intersect $S^c$, in other words, is contained in $S$.

No point of $S$ is a limit point of $S^c$. Therefore if $x\in S$ there is an open ball around $x$ contained in $S$. So $S$ is open.

Comment: what is the difference between your definition of limit point (open ball) versus the definition involving sequence $(x_n) \to x$? It looks like the definition for interior point or something

Comment: Oh, I see your definition is $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence $x_n$ contained in $A$ that converges to $x$ ? My definition is every open ball around $x$ intersects $A$. they are equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Don’t bother with a proof by contradiction: you can use the hypothesis to show directly that $S$ is a union of open sets and hence is open. The hypothesis implies that if $p\in S$, then $p$ has an open nbhd such that ... ?

Comment: Ok I see, I used a different definition for limit point which is hard to use. Did not know about that open ball definition.

Comment: @FemaleTank: Yes, the open ball definition often makes matter *much* simpler. And it works in spaces in which the sequence definition does not.